# Ambient Occlusion Baking Issue

Tags: baking

[image]

This is the problem I have. The rear of my model is not being baked.
I tried correcting Z-fighting with "merge by distance" but it did not work.
I tried moving the model which is baked.
I looked through the world panel to see if I could modify any environmental light but I figured out that I could not. It is weird to me that the front part of the model is being baked but not the rear part.
I tried applying spot lights and playing wih the distance between the projected parts and the low poly model but non of it worked.

I could read topics with the same problem but they give solutions I have already tried like I mentioned above.

I could bake the UV correctly though, this is Ambient Occlusion baking and I am using the Cycles rendering Engine.

Comment: Something to try: Just to make sure that the dark parts of the bake are not caused by hidden objects in the scene, go to the Outliner and disable the the little Camera icon, (the "Disable in Renders" option) for all the objects that should not be included in the bake. For example, I notice that the retop V1 and retop V2 objects are hidden (eye icon greyed out) but the camera,(render) icons are not greyed out.

Comment: We'd need the file, with both high and low poly to make sure, but the first thing I'd check would be high poly normals.

Comment: Oh, thank you so much ! It was indeed the camera which I did not disable.